# Mixing Windows Azure Accelerator for Web Deploy and Windows Azure Accelerator for Umbraco within the same Web Roles.

Tags: azure, umbraco

Is there a hybrid accelerator that allows me to mix both Umbraco and plain MVC3 projects together within the same Web Roles?

So if I was running six sites, 3 that were Umbraco and 3 that were just MVC projects is there a hybrid accelerator that allows me to deploy a minimum of just 2 Web Roles (for SLA) or will I always need at least 4?

Comment: I'm looking at doing the same sort of thing if possible. Did you have any luck?

Comment: @Shea, Not since I put the question down. I've stepped away from web dev for a while on another project but about to get back into another Umbraco project. Will post here if I find something worthwhile.

Comment: Sounds good, appreciate it. I'll be moving forward with this as well, so I may end up answering your question myself if I find something good.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't have a super awesome answer for you, but here's what I found:

I *have* managed to get the Umbraco accelerator working with additional MVC apps on a single web role. The solution that I'm currently going with just defines the additional apps as web sites using the sites node in the Azure service definition file. However, for this to work you must modify the Umbraco accelerator code or it will delete your sites right out from under you:

Line 305 of the `SyncHelper.cs` file should be changed to something like this:

```
if (!sitesToAdd.Remove(name) && name != "web" && !name.StartsWith("someprefix")) {
```

The "someprefix" string can be anything of your choosing, but you must use the prefix on all your website names to keep the accelerator from removing them.

If you really don't want to have to republish to make code changes, I did find one other interesting thing. If you don't mind having all of your other MVC apps on the box running as independent websites (already similar to my solution anyway), you can just upload them to blob storage like it was another Umbraco website. It seemed to work fine although this definitely doesn't give you the same control and ease of use as the web role accelerator. I chose not to use this solution since I didn't want to incur the additional storage transactions.

On a final note, I believe it would still be possible to actually combine the Umbraco and web role accelerators if someone really wanted to take the time and go through the code and make it happen. That person is not me at this point :)